# xcode5 add new referencing outlet

Tags: xcode5

Hi I have Just Update my xcode to xcode5, but I have no idea how to add new referencing outlet using xcode 5 by ctrl-drag and drop the label or buttons just like previous what I did in xcode 4.5

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 15):

Open your storyboard and click on the editor button (seems like a suit) and select the .h associate to your view :

[image]

Then, ctrl drag the UI element from the storyboard or xib on your header file or your .m between @interface and @end.

XCode will show you a pop-up with some options :

[image]

And you will obtain the following code :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;

@end
```

Comment: This just does not work for me. I am able to drag the blue line but then no code is generated...

Comment: What does not work for you ? I tried again with storyboard and its work perfectly. I edit my answer to show you the result.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for me either using xcode 6.  Followed your procedure exactly.  See blue line,  No code generated.  Try again.

Comment: I just tried and it's work for Xcode 6.1.1.
Are you dragging the blue line in the `@interface` in .h or `@implementation` in .m ?

Answer (score 3):

Today, I also encountered this problem. And I resolved it like this:

[image: Solute Step]

Comment: Please add parts of link in answer

Comment: Good answer, because each scene has to have a class, so that elements on that scene can be added as properties of that class... or maybe someone can share more info why newer xcode fail to have the class

Answer (score 3):

I was missing the obvious myself here. To add a new Referencing Outlet (I'm using XCode 9.0) I did the following:

1. Ensure the storyboard and header file are both open and visible
2. Right-click on the control and drag the + symbol by `New Referencing Outlet` to the line in your header file where you want the new variable reference.

Answer (score 1):

Start by selecting the ViewController you want the outlet in your storyboard.

Then click on the suite symbol on the upper right and make sure the storyboard is on the left and the header of the custom UIViewController is on the right, you can click on automatic on top of the right file to get some help with this.

Then ctrl drag the label from the storyboard on the left between @interface and @end in the header on the right.