# Reference to a Table in a ViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, tableview

I want to change that separator line color, that one that separate the lines, in my `UITableView`. I have this code in my views.

```
self.tableview.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:115/255.0 green:83/255.0 blue:14/255.0 alpha:1];
```

I don't have any problems in my `UITableViewControllers`, but in my `ViewController` that has a `TableView` component I can't do this away.

Help please.

Comment: you need to connect `IBOutlet` to tableview in xib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have reference to your UITableView. You can achieve this by adding

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

To your .h class file and then add New Referencing Outlet in your Interface Builder.
If you don't know how to create referencing outlet take a look at this post:
[xcode5 add new referencing outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149821/xcode5-add-new-referencing-outlet)