# Setting up UITableView methods for reloading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I followed a tutorial on [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/), and formatted 2 strings to be displayed in the table that I declared in the ViewController.h. Because my app is parsing a downloaded JSON file, it take a second or two to fill the strings with the variables I want to display. My problem is that it only reloads when the cell reenter the view. What I need to do is reload the methods below when the parsing has finished.

Here are my ViewController.m methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_recipies count];
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath       *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_recipies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_weatherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Updated");

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` will reload your table view and call `tableview: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as well. (If necessary replace `self.tableView` with whatever variable you're using to store a reference to your table view.)

Comment: I tried [self.tableview reloadData] at the end of my parsing method and nothing changed. Also, where would I put the tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: You already have tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath defined above, so no extra work is needed there. Replace self.tableView with whatever variable you're using to store a reference to your table view.

Comment: I'm going to sound dumb saying this, but I don't think I have a variable storing a reference to my tableview. The only code for it is what I posted, and I have the dataSource and delegate referenced to the main View Controller.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard/Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes, my storyboard file is just Main.Storyboard

Comment: You can [add a reference through storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149821/xcode5-add-new-referencing-outlet). In Xcode 6 the split window editor looks like two arrows pointing away from each other. If you're writing an app where a table view is the main item of a view controller, consider using a [table view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/) instead of manually adding a table view to a view controller.

Comment: It's not the 2 arrows pointing away, it's the assistant editor when is the 2 overlapping circles. Thanks for the help, referencing it as an IBOutlet worked.